# MySQL collation for Portugese

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Is there a way in MySQL to have character collated as per the Portugese language? In the same way there is utf8_spanish_ci or Spanish. Or is there a way to add new collations?

There are the following characters:

```
ç (Gonçalves)
ã (Guimarães)
õ (Simões)
â (Tânger)
ô (Pôrto)
ê (Gouvêa)
é (Féria)
í (Vinícius)
ó (Grijó)
ú (Araújo)
á (Tomás)
ñ (Núñez)
```

When using utf8_general_ci searching for 'Gonçalves' would also return 'Goncalves'. I need these to be treated separately by MySQL.

Comment: use `latin1_danish_ci` as the collation . http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_danish_ci.html

Comment: This treats CcÇç as the same.

Comment: in the document it has different values. strange

Comment: have you tried changing collation and char set

Comment: You can check the collations [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) .  I agree that danish seems to do what you want for _those_ accents than spanish or spanish2.

Comment: Coming to this in a few hours?
Is there not a way to add coalitions? I looked in information_schema and this lists the coalitions, though I can't see the actual character tables in there.

Comment: @KohjahBreese - There is a web page in the manual that explains the gory details of creating your own collation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the collation and character set.
This is an example create statement for accepting Portugese characters.

```
CREATE DATABASE dansih_db CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci;
```

try altering Character Sets and Collation in you DB
Example output for above character set and collation

[[image: Check this output[1]

Answer (score 0):

According to http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html, and tested in MySQL, the latin1_general_ci is the collation that correctly differentiates between the characters the OP has identified

It also sorts it properly, and does not transform Ç into C for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The above are answers for the user's question but I hope it's appropriate to warn: with a typical Portuguese collation those characters would not all be separate for searching. Wikipedia explains in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography
"Accented letters and digraphs are not counted as separate characters for collation purposes." and Unicode's common language data repository explains in https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/collation/pt.xml "The root collation order is valid for this language." So MySQL's default Unicode-collation-algorithm collations would usually be desirable.