# What COLLATE should i set to use all kind of possible languages?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, collation

I have a column called `username`, i want the user to be able to insert text in japanese, roman, arabic, korean, and everything that is possible, including special chars [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:All_languages], what `COLLATE` should i set on my database and tables?

I'm using `utf_general_ci`, i'm new so i don't know if this is the best `COLLATE` for my needs. I need to choose the right `COLLATE` to avoid sql error, because i will not use `preg_replace` or a function to replace special chars, i will only use `prepared statement` to avoid SLQ injection and protect by database.

Comment: To use *actual* UTF-8 in MySQL you can pick any collation that shows up when you run `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%'` in your server. But one thing is charset and another thing is collation. For that, you need to figure out your preferred [case/accent sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html), as well as the advanced rules for character comparison and sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First choice (MySQL 8.0):  `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`
- Second choice (as of 5.6):  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`
- Third choice (5.5+):  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- Before 5.5, you can't handle all of Chinese, nor Emoji:  `utf8_unicode_ci`

The numbers refer to Unicode standards 9.0, 5.20, and (no number) 4.0.

No collation is good for sorting *all* languages at the same time.  Spanish, German, Turkish, etc, have quirks that are incompatible.  The collations above are the 'best' general purpose ones available.

utf8mb4 handles all characters yet specified by Unicode (including Cherokee, Klingon, Cuneiform, Byzantine, etc.)

**If Portuguese is the focus:**

See https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ and  [MySQL collation for Portugese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507251/mysql-collation-for-portugese) .

Study [*this for 8.0*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) or [*this for pre 8.0*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) to see which utf8/utf8mb4 collation comes closest to sorting Portuguese 'correctly'.  Perhaps `utf8mb4_danish_ci` or `utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci` would be best.

(Else go with the 'choices' listed above.)

Comment: interesting, i will seach a bit about `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. And my mysql version is `10.1.37`.

Comment: MariaDB 10.1 approximates MySQL 5.6, so the 'best' for you is `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  (I just now checked 10.1.33.)

Comment: I have 2 questions, 1 - how do you choose the best `COLLATE` for a MySQL version? I made some reserch and i will use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` and i will see if its good. 2 -  Should i add `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese'); //ppl said that i should use the language of my country` on top of my file? I think it could help to replace special chars, but iam not sure, i just meet this function some days ago

Comment: Actually i asked if it's recommended to use `setLocale()`,  i mean if there's one words that a `COLLATE` can't handle, it will print out on the screen a sql error, so to avoid this error `setLocale()` maybe could help (i'm not sure about it). But anyways it's a topic for another question, thanks

Comment: @user236945896 - Screen rendering is a different issue.  What OS, what 'screen'?

Comment: This only could happens on a `SELECT` query that the user have permition to modify the values on the `WHERE` clause. Example: if your `COLLATE` is `latin1_swedish_ci` and you have a query like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '壱げ'` (this is just a short example, i use prepared statements with placeholders), this will print out on the screen a error https://pastebin.com/YAbEHWgm this happens because `壱` is not supported by `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Comment: This is why i made this question, even though `Illegal mix of collations` error does not print out any private info, i wanted to avoid this kind of error. I will choose one of the `COLLATE`s that you listed above.

Comment: @user236945896 - Either _connection_ parameters or the column definition is saying latin1.  Show us both.  Plan on moving everything to utf8mb4, away from latin1.

Comment: Let me just add that for Portuguese characters the correct collation is latin1_general_ci

Comment: @FilT - What are the extra characters and rules for sorting Portuguese?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that in case you are using pre 8.0 the best one is latin1_general_ci. Otherwise you do not have utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci available which might indeed be the best

Comment: MariaDB 10.10 -- and even newer Collation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 5.5.3 or higher, I would recommend UTF-8 character encoding `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` . AFAIK it supports most, if not all languages, and implements the Unicode standard for sorting and comparison. As a second choice, have a look at `utf8mb4_general_ci`, which may be faster but also less accurate.

See [this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) for (many) more details, or check out the [official MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html).

Below 5.5.3, `utf8_unicode_ci`  is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

`COLLATION` refers to ordering (as in comparisons in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`); you should really ask about `CHARACTER SET`:

- Pre-5.5.3:  utf8 (aka utf8mb3) handles all languages, except for a few Chinese characters and Emoji.
- 5.5.3 forward:  utf8mb4 - Handles everything.  Outside of MySQL, it is spelled "UTF-8".